# How to fetch Exact events from EKEvents?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

I have access all events from my **simulator calender**.
The `array` looks like very ugly.

My code is,

```
(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc]init];

    NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1;
    NSDate *oneDayAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    // Create the end date components
    NSDateComponents *oneYearFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    oneYearFromNowComponents.month = 1;
    NSDate *oneYearFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneYearFromNowComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    // Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneDayAgo endDate:oneYearFromNow calendars:nil];

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate
    NSArray *events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"The content of array is%@",events);


}
```

## My Output is

[image]

**My Question is**:

How can i only show the Highlighted string(show image), that's what I can display on my `table view cell`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `for (EKEvent *event in events){ NSLog(@"%@",event.title); }`

Comment: Thanks a lot working fine!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`EKEvent` is descendant of [EKCalendarItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekcalendaritem?language=objc) so you can get that property by calling `event.title`.